# Creating weak entity in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

When modeling identifying relationships, I have a primary key for the strong entity. Then I add an identifier attribute and a foreign key for the weak entity. The primary key of the weak entity is the composite of the identifier attribute and the foreign key.

In asp.net I wrote this code:

```
//strong entity model:
[Key]
public int id;

//weak entity model:
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public int id { get; set; }
[Key, Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Strong")]
public int StrongId { get; set; }
public virtual Strong Strong { get; set; }
```

But it's not working. The problem is, first, I can't add anything to the weak table, and second, I'm not sure if the database generates unique ids only for weak entities related to one strong entity.

(This is where I saw how to use foreign key: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application )

Comment: Is this any good?[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686367/map-weak-entity-by-using-code-first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686367/map-weak-entity-by-using-code-first)

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to do it with data annotations like [key] and [foreignkey].

Comment: I think this is a form of purism that doesn't work well with EF. It's much easier to let the weak entity have its own singular surrogate key and a regular foreign key to the strong entity. By making the foreign key (or the `Strong` property) required you can still achieve the goal that a weak entity can't exist on its own.